# Can I connect buck boost converters back to back?

Tags: buck, boost, converter

I need to power a Bluetooth speaker **(Beatbox Portable)** with a battery pack while also allowing DC power in.

I also want to use the input DC power to charge the four cell lithoum ion battery pack.

Can I use buck and boost converters as in the circuit below?

**D1 and D2** are safety diodes to prevent current from flowing in the opposite direction.

[image]

The below image is a 2nd option that I'm still trying to achieve.
I am not sure if I will be able to as the space inside the speaker is limited.

Other side questions:

1. What happens if the BMS is triggered due to a short circuit or low battery voltage?
2. Will connecting the main DC input (18.5V) reset the BMS?
3. Is it OK to leave the BMS connected to the load?
4. Can [this charger board](https://www.aliexpress.us/item/3256805940909646.html?spm=a2g0o.productlist.main.1.2447482ckhuz03&algo_pvid=d63e9d81-bdb8-4962-b378-6ba756e38827&algo_exp_id=d63e9d81-bdb8-4962-b378-6ba756e38827-0&pdp_npi=4%40dis%21USD%217.61%211.22%21%21%2155.21%21%21%4021038edf16999713241697606ef5a9%2112000035878042363%21sea%21US%21124783082%21&curPageLogUid=VtQJzdXjLaJv#nav-specification) work for five cells in this application?

[image]

I'm still in the concept and testing phase. I haven't chosen any component yet, but I was looking at the XL6009 buck+boost converters.

Here is the DC power supply:

[image]

Another Potential Solutions:

1- Using [this USB-C charging board for 4S or 5S cells](https://www.aliexpress.us/item/3256804838157423.html?spm=a2g0o.productlist.main.113.1bbe47eefUOsYe&algo_pvid=3be99725-929b-40f4-901e-f101ae6f063a&algo_exp_id=3be99725-929b-40f4-901e-f101ae6f063a-56&pdp_npi=4%40dis%21USD%212.05%211.78%21%21%212.05%21%21%40211b88ec16999669212135408efe6f%2112000031374567048%21sea%21US%21124783082%21&curPageLogUid=us3XCukPJNoF) with a manual switch to select between DC input or battery pack.

[image]

Comment: @All - The long comment chain has exceeded what is reasonable for comments. Therefore comments so far have been moved to chat & should be continued there (see the comment below). || As this bulk moving of comments to chat can only be done once per question, any further comments posted here might be deleted without notice. *Keep it in chat now, please!* || All relevant improvements to the question decided during the chat, should be made via an [edit] (without *expanding* the question) not as a comment. When someone has got enough information to post an answer, please answer it as usual. Thanks.

Comment: *Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149702/discussion-on-question-by-p-la-can-i-connect-buck-boost-converters-back-to-back); please do not continue the discussion here.*

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider using a battery charger IC with the ability to seamlessly switch between DC Input and Battery Input. Its normally called Dynamic Power Management (DPM) and Dynamic Power-Path Management (DPPM).

[image: MPS Power Path Managment Example]

[MPS have a nice primer page explaining some of the concepts](https://www.monolithicpower.com/en/power-path-management-in-charger-ics)

I'd highly recommend designing a circuit or using a module that implements the battery management and power path functionality as it'll make your life much easier as battery charging can be a pain to implement and you'll save yourself a lot of space with a more integrated solution which is something I think you'd find valuable being space constrained in your application.

Comment: Thank you for sharing this. This is what I want exactly. but I'm looking for a ready-made solution to just plug in. I don't want to do a custom PCB. I'm constrained with the battery compartment for the battery space. inside the speaker, I've some space for the Buck/Boost converters. (the battery compartment fits 6 D cell batteries). Can't something similar to the DPPM be achieved with Buck/Boost converters and a BMS?....